# Как настроить .htaccess для mvc в subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, mvc

Возникает `500 Internal Server Error` на субдомене *ru.site.com*. Проблема в `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

На домене *site.com* все страницы переводят на *index.php*, а на сабдомене уже не работает.

`site.com/test/1/` - работает норм

и копия сайта только на сабдомене

`ru.site.com/test/1/` - выдает ошибку 500

В чем может быть проблема, кто знает как правильно прописать `.htaccess`?

Comment: А не может быть так, что в корне домена есть index.php, а у субдомена - нет?

Comment: И что про ошибку написано в логе апача?